# is it possible to fetch and update committed values in offset from kafka topic using mule 4

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, mulesoft, mule4, mule-connector

I have a topic with values of 100 rows and all are committed. I want to fetch the value and key of offset '50' (say) and update the value of that particular offset and push back the change. Please kindly suggest all possible ways to overcome this scenario.

Comment: What have you tried? What were the results?

Comment: @aled, I have tried using the seek operator in mulesoft, but it seems not to return any payload with the values I expect, rather returns a normal log line saying 'Seeking offset 50 from partition <topic-partition>.

Comment: Note that the seek operation doesn't return a payload accordingly to the documentation.